# PouchDB compact() call

Tags: pouchdb

I have pouchDB replicated from couchdb (couchappy.com). Replication is not live. I just run it under certain conditions (e.g.load/initialization of application, changing of certain options by end user, etc).

I have deleted some docs in couchdb and those appear as "deleted" in pouchdb. Then I wanted to compact my pouchdb: db.compact() call. But this call seems not to do much for deleted docs.

Note that I have already compacted counchdb.

I am using pouchdb 2.2.0.

Does anyone of you guys know what is compact() call actually doing on pouchdb?
Also, how to get rid of the "deleted" docs?

Cheers, Alberto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CouchDB and PouchDB always keep a "tombstone" revision for deleted documents, because otherwise funky things would happen during replication.  So those deleted docs don't go away during compaction;  compaction just gets rid of any revisions older than the most recent one.

There is also a "purge" command that can really eliminate a document and its history, but it's pretty drastic, and most of the time you don't want to do it unless you have to ([source](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents)).  Also, it's not supported in PouchDB yet, although it's [in progress](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/802).

If you're just worried about a doc taking up space, instead of simply calling `pouch.remove()`, you can do:

```
pouch.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
  var deletedDoc = {
    _id      : doc._id,
    _rev     : doc._rev,
    _deleted : true
  };
  return pouch.put(doc);
}).then(function (res) {
  // etc.
}).catch(function (err) {
  // etc.
};
```

Comment: The scenario is following
(1) Run replication in client -> get doc A; (2) Delete doc A in couchDB; (3) Run replication in client -> doc A get the "deleted" flag on. I am doing only a one way replication so I do not see the need of keeping those "thombstone" in the client side. I understood that there is already a local variable in client keeping track of when the last replication happened. What do you think?

Comment: The tombstones are a pretty fundamental part of making sure that replication is consistent across many clients/servers. E.g. you could imagine a situation where, between steps 2 and 3, some other server in a multi-master setup modifies the same doc (without deleting), then both servers try to sync with the client.  The client needs to know that a conflict exists in case you need to handle it.  The [Couch docs on replication](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html) may be helpful here if you're curious to know more.

Comment: So if a purge is performed in CouchDb will this then propagate to the PouchDb instances and thus clean up the tombstones?  Is there a better way?

Comment: purge() is not implemented in PouchDB yet; it's an open issue. Are the tombstones really taking up that much space? In our implementation it should just be the size of `{_id: 'foo', _deleted: true}`; none of the old data is kept around.